# Collision Detection and Response with Multiple Objects

Tags: collision-detection, collision

So I've implemented collision detection for convex polytopes in 3D space using GJK to detect a collision and EPA to get the resolution vector. That works well when an object is only colliding with one other object, how do you handle a collision when one object is colliding with multiple objects? Consider the following scenario, the red box is the player walking to the right and the two black boxes are just some objects the player can walk on (being subjected by gravity moves the player down inside these objects):
[image]
The minimum resolution vector for the collision with the right box is in the direction going directly left and the minimum resolution vector for the collision with the left box is in the direction going straight up. Because the boxes can appear in an arbitrary order, first resolving the player from the right object results in an abrupt stop. Then the player would get resolved from the left object, moving him/her up. The effect is that the player has hit a wall. Starting with the left object first alleviates this problem, because then the player isn't colliding with the right object. So maybe there is some kind of distinct order in which to apply the resolution vectors?

How do you prevent this from happening? I obviously don't want the player to be running atop of flush objects and then suddenly stop.

The objects and player can be an arbitrary convex polytope in 3D space also, the solution should be able to handle the same situation if the player was sliding along a wall or jumped and slide across the ceiling.